# Configure Netgear FVS318v3 for VPN Pass Through

Tags: vpn, cisco, netgear

I've replaced a Linksys Router for my home network with a Netgear FVS318v3 VPN Firewall.  The laptop I'm bringing home from work could connect with VPN over the router but cannot connect with the new Netgear firewall.  It spits out:

Error 5 no hostname exists for this connection entry.  Unable to make VPN connection.

What do I need to configure on the Netgear firewall to enable VPN pass through from the laptop out through the firewall?  The reference manual isn't much help and a Google search doesn't retrieve much besides general information that the firewall does support a VPN pass through connection.

In Response:  I believe it's Cisco IpSec but it's pre-installed on the Laptop.  I'm not familiar with configuring the client and would prefer to stay away from messing around with it.  That error is being spit out by the Cisco client in a Windows dialog box.  The Netgear firewall has had no configuration besides plugging it in - everything is defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config file for the Cisco VPN was corrupted/blown away.  After getting the file replaced I port forwarded ports 500, 4500 and 10000 to allow the VPN passthrough.

Answer (score 0):

We just got rid of three of those.. (finally upgraded some remote sites) and you know, I don't think they have any option for that (not that version even with up to date firmware).. however, we never had trouble connecting PPTP through them..

What sort of VPN are you attempting? (Cisco IPSec?)

Where does it spit that out? (In the Netgear logs?)

Have you got any SiteToSite VPN's configured on your Netgear device?, if so, and you are attempting an IPSec VPN, it may be incompatible.. (which is probably why my predecessor configured our clients to use PPTP).

Is your work VPN configured with NAT-T? (ask) If not, you will find that it will not work.